# Getting a Document With Exactly the Same Keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a document format in my coms collection:

```
{
    "recipients": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
    }
}
```

I want to get all documents which have the exact same keys. In other words, in the above example, if I query for "key1", "key2", "key3", I get the above document. If, on the other hand, I have the following document:

```
{
    "recipients": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4",
    }
}
```

Querying for "key1", "key2", "key3" should return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution with $exists:

```
db.collection.find({
   "recipients.key1":{
      $exists:true
   },
   "recipients.key2":{
      $exists:true
   },
   "recipients.key3":{
      $exists:true
   },
   "recipients.key4":{
      $exists:false
   }
})
```

But this require to know all other possible keys and can be quite painfull to write..